# AppDelegate for transparentnavigation bar background swift 5

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to make the navigation bar to be completely transparent color in appDelegate.

I tried under codes but it still not fully transparent. All the solutions I found was the code I'm using. Did I miss something? Thanks.

```
   func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    
    // Sets background to a blank/empty image
    UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forBarMetrics: .Default)
    // Sets shadow (line below the bar) to a blank image
    UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
    // Sets the translucent background color
    UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0)
    // Set translucent. (Default value is already true, so this can be removed if desired.)
    UINavigationBar.appearance().translucent = true
    
        return true
    }
```

[image: What I have][image: What I want]

Comment: It should work. It's working for me as well. Are you setting navigation bar setting somewhere else as well?

Comment: @VedSharma Just checked, only in app delegate. I tried to remove the view controller and make a new one just in case. It is still the same like there is another view with half alpha on it.

Comment: Can you please show your viewcontroller IB?

Comment: @VedSharma Silly me. I found the problem. I'm using container view so the inner views are also having the same gradience color. No wonder it is not matching because one's background color is extended to superview and the other one is only up to safe view. I thought I was experience some new bugs. lol